# Checking if a certain Input was entered

Tags: c

So I am writing a program that takes a Postfix Expression and evaluates what ever the user inputs. However, I'm trying to input a option where it asks the user if they want to input a expression. If yes, the program will then ask the user to input a expression. If, no the program will display a message saying ending the program. However the code I have right now is infinitely looping no matter what input I type in. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
int main() {
  int op1,op2,val;
  char x, response;
  stack s;
  init(&s);

 printf("Would you like to evaluate a Postfix Expression? (Y/N) \n");

 if ((response=getchar()) == 'Y' || 'y') {

printf("Enter a Postfix Expression: ");

while((x=getchar())!= '\n') {

if (isalpha(x)) {
  printf("Invalid Character detected, please check your evaluation.\n");
  exit(0);
  }

if (isdigit(x)) {
        push(&s,x-48);
  }
  
    else if (!isspace(x)) {
        op2=pop(&s);
        op1=pop(&s);
        val=evaluate(x,op1,op2);
        push(&s,val);
    }
 }

  val=pop(&s);
  printf("\nValue of expression: %d\n",val); 
 }

 else {
 printf("Ending Program, Have a Great Day!\n");
   }
 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with consistent indentation.

Comment: You have two problems with the code you show, both related: The first is that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`**. The second problem is that the `getchar` return type is *crucial* for the `EOF` check you *must* have.

Comment: Oh and `(response=getchar()) == 'Y' || 'y'` is wrong as well. It's actually equal to `((response=getchar()) == 'Y') || 'y'`. I.e. you compare the result of `getchar` with `'Y'`, and then use the result of the comparison (which will be `0` or `1`) for the logical operator. As `'y'` is always "true" (it's non-zero) the whole expression will always be true. You need to compare `response` to `'Y'` and `'y'` *separately* (`(response=getchar()) == 'Y' || response == 'y'`). And remember what I told you above about `getchar` returning an `int`.

Comment: So I changed the getchar() into a scanf() and the code is almost working. When I go to type Y, it skips the while(x=getchar) condition and prints out a random number. It doesn't even let me type my evaluation I want. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Remember that `Enter` key you probably use to terminate each input? That is added to the input buffer as a newline. Most `scanf` format specifiers skip leading white-space (including newline), but `%c` does *not*. There are many hints about this all over the Internet, including quite a few here on Stack Overflow.